# Task Scheduler Batch file launches Python Script and randomly does not produce output ~20% of the time

Tags: python, batch-file

Every day a CSV is posted on a public website sometime roughly between 9:30 am and 10:30 am. I have a python script that scrapes this website every 30 seconds then sends an email when the new CSV is posted. 
(example: http://mis.nyiso.com/public/csv/damlbmp/20191119damlbmp_zone.csv )

This python script works 100% of the time when I manually run it from Spyder, but for some reason is inconsistent when I use the task scheduler to call a batch file. The task scheduler will always call the batch file (the command prompt window pops up on time) but sometimes will not produce the email. It seems to be totally random and doesn't depend on what time the CSV file is released (for example if the CSV is released closer to 10:00 instead of 9:30).

My first thought was possibly that my computer had too many other tasks running at the same time and maybe it was a memory error or a concurrent python session error, but the email fails commonly on weekends when I am not using my computer.

The extra weird part is that I have this process in place for two different websites (one releases at 9:30, one releases at 12:00 pm) and often one email will be produced and the other will not.

**Python Script scraping website and sending email:**

```
import requests, smtplib, datetime, pandas as pd, time

x = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

file_date = (x.strftime("%Y%m%d"))

urlFile = file_date +"damlbmp_zone"


Filename = "/Users/renoira/Python/Data/NY_Clears.csv"
url = 'http://mis.nyiso.com/public/csv/damlbmp/%s.csv'%(urlFile) 


while True:
    try:
        print("Try to execute commands")
        if requests.get(url).status_code == 404:
            print("File not ready")
            raise Exception("Timeout")
        print("Email Sending")
        break
    except:
        print("Timeout: sleep for 30 seconds and try again")
        time.sleep(30)


url = 'http://mis.nyiso.com/public/csv/damlbmp/%s.csv'%(urlFile)  
r = requests.get(url)

with open(Filename, 'wb') as f:  
    f.write(r.content)

nyClears = pd.read_csv(Filename)

###Formatting email, create dataframe then html1 = df.render() etc

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
#from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

def send_email():
#email body and html table summary

send_email()
```

**Batch file called by task scheduler:**

```
cd /d %~dp0
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\renoira\Python\Daily Model Runs\NY Price Scrape.py"
```

**Summary:**

I have a python script that scrapes a website every 30 seconds then sends an email when the website is updated. It works 100% of the time when I run it in Spyder but when I use the task scheduler to call a batch file it only works sometimes.